# The val() function not working on indexed jQuery elements

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the following html:

```
<div>
  <select name="a">
   ...
  </select>
  <select name="b">
   ...
  </select>
</div>
```

There may be multiple div's. The condition is that both selects have to be selected in a single div before doing other stuff. Instead of checking each of them separately:

```
$('select[name="a"]').each(function() {
  $(this).val();
  ...
});

$('select[name="b"]').each(function() {
  $(this).val();
  ...
});
```

I have to check them both at the same time:

```
var $elementAs = $('select[name="a"]');
var $elementBs = $('select[name="b"]');

for (i=0; i<$elementAs.length; i++) {
  if ($elementAs[i].val() && $elementBs[i].val()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, jQuery complaints that `$elementAs[i].val` is not a function.
How do I iterate jQuery objects using the `for` loop and check their values?

Comment: I doubt the vote relates to the typo, just FWIW. (But I wouldn't really know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index into a jQuery object, you get the raw value at that position (usually a DOM element), not a jQuery object. If you want a jQuery object with a set of elements in it and want to access the element at index `i`, you either wrap the result using [`$()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery):

```
$($elementAs[i])
```

or use [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$elementAs.get(i)
```

But you don't need a jQuery object in this case. If you know they're `select` elements, you can just use the [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement)'s `value` property:

```
if ($elementAs[i].value && $elementBs[i].value) {
```